# Game of Life Ocaml with Matrix

Tags: arrays, matrix, random, ocaml

I have generated a matrix for my Game of Life, and I'm trying to make it so that it loops through and continuously prints out the next generation, I am using a code I found online, and it doesn't seem to work. Here is my code

```
let generation = ref 1
let get g x y =
  try g.(x).(y)
  with _ -> 0
 ;;
let neighbourhood g x y =
  (get g (x-1) (y-1)) +
  (get g (x-1) (y  )) +
  (get g (x-1) (y+1)) +
  (get g (x  ) (y-1)) +
  (get g (x  ) (y+1)) +
  (get g (x+1) (y-1)) +
  (get g (x+1) (y  )) +
  (get g (x+1) (y+1)) 

let next_cell g x y =
  let n = neighbourhood g x y in
  match g.(x).(y), n with
  | 1, 0 | 1, 1                      -> 0  (* lonely *)
  | 1, 4 | 1, 5 | 1, 6 | 1, 7 | 1, 8 -> 0  (* overcrowded *)
  | 1, 2 | 1, 3                      -> 1  (* lives *)
  | 0, 3                             -> 1  (* get birth *)
  | _ -> 0

let copy g = Array.map Array.copy g

let rec next g =
  let width = Array.length g
  and height = Array.length g.(0)
  and new_g = copy g in
  for x = 0 to pred width do
    for y = 0 to pred height do
      new_g.(x).(y) <- (next_cell g x y)
    done
  done;
  next new_g

let print g =
  let width = Array.length g
  and height = Array.length g.(0) in
  for x = 0 to pred width do
    for y = 0 to pred height do
      if g.(x).(y) = 0
      then print_char '.'
      else print_char 'o'
    done;
    print_newline()
  done
;;

print_string "Width ";
let num = read_int () in
 print_string "Height";
 let num2 = read_int () in
      while !generation < 100 do 
        let myArray = Array.init num (fun _ -> Array.init num2 (fun _ -> Random.int 2)) in 
        print_string "Generation: "; print_int !generation; print_string "\n";
        print (next myArray);
        generation := !generation +1;
        print_newline();
      done;;
```

It only prints out the initial one and the generation after that rather than a new one. Since the parameters is the original array, however, when I put print (next new_g) it gives me an unbound value, is there a way I can continuously print out the subsequent generations?Shouldn't it overwrite the existing new_g when I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking just at the main while loop, it allocates and initializes a random array each time around the loop. It doesn't seem like this could be right.

I also don't see how the function `next` could work, as it never returns. Its last action is to call itself again, unconditionally.

**Update**

If you change the last line of `next` to this:

```
new_g
```

it returns the next generation each time you call it.

Here's a way to drive the code in a functional (rather than imperative) style:

```
let rec generation n array =
    if n < 100 then
        begin
        (* Print the array *);
        generation (n + 1) (next array)
        end
```

The outermost code might look like this:

```
let myArray =
    Array.init num
        (fun _ -> Array.init num2 (fun _ -> Random.int 2))
in
generation 0 myArray
```

Comment: So I should have the array initialized and printed, then have a while loop? How would I fix the "next" function though, that snippet of code was found online, and I'm not really sure how to tweak it to fit my current goal.

Comment: Another question I had, since you've been helping me quite a lot with OCaml, is how do I install Graphics module, I've followed guides to importing it but it seems it's not installed. Is there a way for me to get it?

Comment: I haven't installed the Graphics module in many years, sorry. The answer might depend somewhat on what system you're using.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, I managed to install the graphics module by reinstalling ocaml, and I will try your modifications right now!

Comment: Whoops, I added begin/end.